# AWS Elastic Beanstalk : Deploying Django application Failed

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to deploy my Django backend for my react application on EB but I can running into an error when I try deploying.I'm not sure how to pull up more details from the log, but I have also attached by requirements.txt file below the error results.

```
2020-11-22 23:44:27    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
2020-11-22 23:44:30    ERROR   [Instance: i-0da4be9088c225a28] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2020-11-22 23:44:31    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-11-22 23:45:33    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

asgiref==3.3.1
attrs==20.3.0
awsebcli==3.19.2
bcrypt==3.2.0
blessed==1.17.11
boto3==1.16.23
botocore==1.19.23
cached-property==1.5.2
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2020.11.8
cffi==1.14.3
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
cryptography==3.2.1
Django==3.1.3
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
django-environ==0.4.5
django-storages==1.10.1
djangorestframework==3.12.2
docker==4.3.1
docker-compose==1.25.5
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
environ==1.0
future==0.16.0
idna==2.10
jmespath==0.10.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
mysqlclient==2.0.1
paramiko==2.7.2
pathspec==0.5.9
Pillow==8.0.1
pycparser==2.20
PyMySQL==0.10.1
PyNaCl==1.4.0
pyrsistent==0.17.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.4
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
termcolor==1.1.0
texttable==1.6.3
urllib3==1.25.11
wcwidth==0.1.9
websocket-client==0.57.0


2020/11/23 01:37:31.395091 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python==2.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29)) (from versions: 8.0.5, 8.0.6, 8.0.11, 8.0.12, 8.0.13, 8.0.14, 8.0.15, 8.0.16, 8.0.17, 8.0.18, 8.0.19, 8.0.20, 8.0.21, 8.0.22)
```

ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python==2.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))

Comment: If you ssh into the EB instance can you run your `requirements.txt` manaully to check if it works as expected?

Comment: @Marcin Yep, I got more info so it seems to be a problem with (mysql-connector-python==2.0.4). Here is the log:  An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] -  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python==2.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29)) (from versions: 8.0.5, 8.0.6, 8.0.11, 8.0.12, 8.0.13, 8.0.14, 8.0.15, 8.0.16, 8.0.17, 8.0.18, 8.0.19, 8.0.20, 8.0.21, 8.0.22)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python==2.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))

Comment: Did you change it to use existing version?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I'm stilling running into an error concerning the mysqlclient. The environment cannot find the sql_config files desppite me adding the necessary packages in the .ebextensions folder. I also check other posts and non of those fixed the error.

Comment: /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-psb7a445/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-psb7a445/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")

Comment: Have you installed mysql client on your EB instance?